# Windows (11) immediate wake up after sleep

Tags: windows, windows-11, sleep, power-management

I'm running Windows 11 on an AMD 5800x. If I put Windows to sleep by selecting the Power button on the Start Menu and then selecting Sleep, Windows goes into Sleep and then immediately wakes up. If I try again it then goes to sleep properly. It does this fairly consistently.

After it wakes up immediately I see the following messages in the Event Log (under the "Kernel-Power" event source), listed in chronological order:

```
The system has resumed from sleep.
```

---

```
Firmware S3 times. ResumeCount: 35, FullResume: 3461, AverageResume: 3461
```

---

```
Firmware S3 times. SuspendStart: 188338442, SuspendEnd: 188338566
```

---

```
The system session has transitioned from 174 to 175.

Reason SxTransition 

BootId: 46
```

---

```
The system session has transitioned from 175 to 177.

Reason Unknown 

BootId: 46
```

---

```
The system has returned from a low power state.

Sleep Time: ‎2023‎-‎05‎-‎30T19:24:40.599748000Z
Wake Time: ‎2023‎-‎05‎-‎30T19:24:57.178939300Z

Wake Source: Unknown
```

---

If I try powercfg then I get this:

```
λ powercfg -lastwake
Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
  Wake Source Count - 0

λ powercfg -waketimers
There are no active wake timers in the system.
```

And this PowerShell command yields the following:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32> Get-ScheduledTask | where {$_.settings.waketorun}

TaskPath                                       TaskName                          State
--------                                       --------                          -----
\Microsoft\Windows\.NET Framework\             .NET Framework NGEN v4.0.30319 6… Disabled
\Microsoft\Windows\.NET Framework\             .NET Framework NGEN v4.0.30319 C… Disabled
\Microsoft\Windows\InstallService\             WakeUpAndContinueUpdates          Disabled
\Microsoft\Windows\InstallService\             WakeUpAndScanForUpdates           Disabled
\Microsoft\Windows\SharedPC\                   Account Cleanup                   Disabled
\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\         Schedule Wake To Work             Disabled
```

This has only started happening recently. The two hardware changes I have made to the system prior to this starting to occur, have to been to upgrade the CPU (3700x -> 5800x) and to remove a Wi-fi network card.

What does "BootId 46" refer to, and any idea how I track down what's causing this?

Edit: As per harrymc's request, I have uploaded a [Power Efficiency Diagnostics](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5148-create-power-efficiency-diagnostics-report-windows-10-a.html) report [here](https://pastebin.com/6dYgttqn) (sorry, it's raw HTML, not sure where I would upload an actual HTML file).

Comment: Please [Create a Power Efficiency Diagnostics](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5148-create-power-efficiency-diagnostics-report-windows-10-a.html) and post online the HTML file.

Comment: [Done](https://pastebin.com/6dYgttqn)

Comment: According to the report, the driver for the Razer Kiyo Pro device is preventing sleep. This seems to be a webcam, so try to turn it off, or disable if it's embedded, and see if sleep works better.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However I tried unplugging the webcam entirely and the problem still occurs.

Comment: Could you make another Power report with the webcam unplugged ?

Comment: I've updated the above pastebin with the new report.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a power problem. You could try to [enable the boot log](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-boot-log-guide/).

Comment: Done - [Boot log](https://pastebin.com/YEYsyUsN). The only odd thing I can see is that it says "Windows 10" when I'm actually running Windows 11 Pro. I might try uninstalling RyzenMaster, as that was the other change I made recently.

Comment: I notice in the boot log that the following drivers couldn't be loaded: `dxgkrnl.sys` and `WdFilter.sys`. The first has to do with the display and the second with Windows Defender. Undo any overclocking  you did with RyzenMaster, as that can cause strange problems.

Comment: In the end i fixed this by changing the Power Plan to "AMD Ryzen Performance Plan" and also editing that plan to disable Wake Timers (more specifically setting "Allow Wake Timers" to false). I assume the latter change is actually what fixed this.

Comment: I agree that it's probably the latter change is the solution, although it will have other side-effects.

Comment: Totally, now I have to press the power button to wake my PC up, but that's more acceptable than having to put it into sleep twice each time. When I have more time I'll try unplugging some of the USB devices to see if I can pinpoint the culprit. Thanks for the help anway.